# Using polyfill for input type 'range' in IE9

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, polyfills

I'm trying to use the HTML5 input type 'range'. This is not supported in IE8 & IE9 and is replaced by input with type 'text'. To make this field work for everybody i'm using a polyfill for the input with type 'range'. 
The polyfill i'm using is: Rangeslider.js (http://andreruffert.github.io/rangeslider.js/)

The html of my inputfield looks like this:

```
<input type="range" id="somefield" name="somefield" required="required" min="0" max="100" step="1" class="className"  value="10">
```

The javascript that runs the polyfill is called on input[type="range"]. Example:

```
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();
```

Somehow the polyfill only works correctly if you call it specifically on the input element, and not on an element with a certain class. So calling it like below will not work (it will render, but the value of the range is not stored in the input element):

```
$('.className').rangeslider();
```

However, IE replaces the input in the DOM with the following HTML:

```
<input name="somefield" class="className" id="somefield" required="required" type="text" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="10">
```

Because the input element now has a different input type, the selector $('input[type="range"]') will not work. using the class or id as selector also doesn't seem to work (in that case the polyfill doesn't update the value of the original element)

In other browsers (Firefox, Chrome) the polyfill does seem to work (when I let it override the native support).

**Question:**
How do I use this polyfill (with what element selector) in IE9?

Comment: What about $('input[name=somefield]').rangeslider()?

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work! I did try that with  $('input[class=className]').rangeslider(), however that didn't seem to work. Using the name works fine. To make this work for all range input fields I can now just write a function that first finds all elements with a certain class and then get the names of those elements to use this selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the mistake. It is possible to use the class as selector. Here is a piece of code that calls the polyfills for multiple range input fields. This avoids using the input type as selector and seems to work in all browsers. Also this works for multiple fields on one page.

```
    $('input.className').each(function(e) {
      $(this).rangeslider();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.

I found it would work for me with the simpler syntax when I didn't try and select with `type=range` but used a class I added to the `input` elements, e.g.:

```
<input type="range" class="slider" />
```

and

```
$('input[class=slider]').rangeslider();
```